# Unable to access system32 folder from Ubuntu 20.10 and 20.04.2 LTS live in USB

Tags: directory

I installed Ubuntu live in USB, both version 20.10 and 20.04.2 LTS. I have a PC with Windows 10 and I tried in both of them. In one, no problem. The other presents that issue. When I try to open `system32` folder, I receive this error:

[image]

Also, when I choose "Try Ubuntu", it shows some errors immediately:

[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to open that directory? As for the pictures of text , text should be in English and in the question not attached as a picture. Are you booting from the live USB?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer.I'm trying to open that directory to replace some corrupted .dll. For the translation in Enghlish, I write it here: "Impossible to show the whole content of “System32”: error in retrieving informations for file “media/Ubuntu/OS/Windows/-System32/Microsoft.Bluetooth/UserService.dll”: input/output error.   Finally, I don't understand what you mean by"  in the question not attached as a picture": do you mean I have to write in plain text what is written in te picture? Thanks